# How can I extract indices from a numpy array where the size of a contiguous matching section is larger than some minimum?

Tags: python, numpy, slice

Suppose I have some array like

```
a = np.random.random(100) > 0.5

array([ True,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True,
        True, False, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True,  True,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True,...
```

I want to find the start indices for all sections of neighbouring `True`s of a minimum of `X`. So for `X=3` in the random snippet above I would want `7`. For `X=2` I should get `0,7,16`.

I can do this with loops but wondering if anyone can tell me a smarter way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`scipy.signal.find_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html#scipy.signal.find_peaks)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

a = np.array([True, True, False, False, True, False, False, True, True,
              True, False, False, True, False, True, False, True, True,
              False, False, False, False, False, True])

_, peaks = find_peaks(np.r_[0, a, 0], width=3)
result = peaks["left_bases"]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[7]
```

For `width=2`, you have:

```
_, peaks = find_peaks(np.r_[0, a, 0], width=2)
result = peaks["left_bases"]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[ 0  7 16]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this answer will be most useful to me as it also provides the `right_bases` (which I will need later). One question - why do you need to prepend the `1` onto the start of `a`?

Comment: @lopsided Actually is a zero, `np.zeros(1)` creates `array([0.])`, the idea is to find the peak at the begining of the array, if there is one.

Comment: Of course it is a zero! Makes sense, but actually we need to put a `0` at the end too to catch peaks at the end of the array. ie, `np.r_[0, a, 0]`. I was actually confused as to why the bases also didn't need shifting but I see from the docs that it returns the "indices in x to the left and right of each peak".

Answer (score 1):

you can use a [convolution](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html#numpy-convolve) :

```
convolution = np.convolve(a, np.array([1, 1, 1]))
np.where(convolution == 3)[0] - 2
```

here the convultion [1, 1, 1] will sum the number with the number before and after it. Then you can find all the indices where 3 is reached and substract 2

here is the generalisation with any number of consecutives

```
def find_consecutive_sequences(number_of_consecutive, a)
    convolution = np.convolve(a, np.ones(shape=(number_of_consecutive)))
    return np.where(convolution == number_of_consecutive)[0] - (number_of_consecutive - 1 )

print(find_consecutive_sequences(3, a))
print(find_consecutive_sequences(4, a))
print(find_consecutive_sequences(5, a))
```

which gives

```
[ 7 16 17 18]
[16 17]
[16]
```

for a (slightly modified to to test the `4` and `5` case) being

```
a = np.array([ True,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True,
        True, False, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True,  True,
       True, True, False, False])
```

Comment: Neat approach! But it does return overlaps, ie, returns `16` and `17` when I only want `16`.

Comment: indeed, if you can I would use the scipy approach since it is cleaner. BTW you could remove consecutive numbers to remove overlaps.

Answer (score 1):

You can find consecutive `True`s by finding the cumulative sum of the boolean array and then splitting that cumsum array into subarrays of consecutive numbers and extracting the starting points of subarrays that are of length `X`.

```
def starting_point_of_X_consecutive_Trues(arr, X):
    arr_cumsum = arr.cumsum()
    splits = np.split(arr_cumsum, np.where(np.diff(arr_cumsum) != 1)[0]+1)
    relevant_points = [splits[0][0]] if len(splits[0]) >= X else []
    relevant_points += [split[1] for split in splits[1:] if len(split)-1 >= X]
    return np.isin(arr_cumsum, relevant_points).nonzero()[0]
```

Output:

```
starting_point_of_X_consecutive_Trues(a, 3) # [7]
starting_point_of_X_consecutive_Trues(a, 2) # [0,7,16]
```